# Eclipse - always autogenerate Ant build files

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a project in Eclipse, I have to manually export the Ant build files to be able to build from command line easily.

Is there any way to make Eclipse generate the Ant build files when creating the project without further interaction?

Answer (score 1):

With standard Eclipse it's possible to generate ant build files (Right click on the project -> Export -> Ant build file) but you need external plugins to generate them automatically (Web Tools Platform if I recall correctly).

Comment: Can you please explain how to set it up